# Further Properties of Adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I recently posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276092/properties-of-adjoints) about adjoint maps. I now want to take this further and show that - with the assumptions as in the original - the minimum polynomials of $T$ and $T^{*}$ are the same. Further to this, what can be said of the eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^{*}$?

Any help would be appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: This is false over $\mathbb{C}$. You need to specify that you're working over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question states that the inner product space is real.

Comment: Questions on SE should be self-contained whenever possible. There's no need to make the reader refer to a different question to obtain a short list of hypotheses that is easy to state.